# Unable to display value in Listview in android

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
    int id;
    String name;
    String phone;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        // Reading all contacts
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
        List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();

        for (Contact cn : contacts) {
            String log = "Id: " + cn.getID() + " ,Name: " + cn.getName()
                    + " ,Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();
            // Writing Contacts to log
            HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

            contact.put(name, cn.getName());
            contact.put(phone, cn.getPhoneNumber());

            contactList.add(contact);
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { cn.getName(),
                            cn.getPhoneNumber() }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                            R.id.mobile });
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Log.d("Name: ", log);
        }

    }

}
```

This is mY code i  am doing every thing fine but some But i am unable to display value on list-view  while when i debugging and then we check adpater value i am getting in that i don't know here am doing mistake plz help.

this my method for getting database value

```
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }
```

Comment: post your `SimpleAdapter`

Comment: SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { cn.getName(),
                            cn.getPhoneNumber() }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                            R.id.mobile });
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Hint for performance: take the `SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { cn.getName(),
                            cn.getPhoneNumber() }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                            R.id.mobile });
            list.setAdapter(adapter);` out of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
  SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "name",
                            "phoneNumber" }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                            R.id.mobile });
```

the 2nd last argument here is supposed to be a column name not value.

Comment: how do you know that those string values should be hardcoded as `name` and `phoneNumber`?

Comment: Coz when break Point on list.setAdapter(adapter); line and pres f my loop run 5 time coz i sent 5 id in database

Comment: @user3432979 i don't know what you mean, but the answer to the question is still up to your adapter code, we don't know what you're doing there and how you treat `new String[]` and `contactList`